# How do i sort elements in an array, containing both string and integers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say i have an array containing (randomly) both integers and string elements:

```
var array = ["T", 5, 2, 9, "A"];
```

The possible elements, or reference, are:

```
var ref = ["A", "K", "Q", "J", "T", 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2];
```

Where A is the highest (most valuable), the K the second most valuable, and so on.
As most of you can see, this represents the diffrent cards in a deck of cards.

How should go about and sort my `array` above, to get the output of:

```
array = ["A", "T", 9, 5, 2];
```

Since i'm trying to learn javascript, i would prefer a pure javascript solution, but i am also wondering if there is a jQuery function for doing this task?

Comment: "pure javascript" is a misnomer. Never say that phrase again.

Comment: @BradM May I ask you why? As an example, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) uses exactly this phrase.

Comment: @BradM "pure javascript" is a colloquial way of saying "without jQuery". This question is legit.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to VisionN's approach, here's a way to avoid needing `indexOf`. I've replaced the reference array with an object literal (note: this does look kinda weird):

```
var array = ["T", 5, 2, 9, "A"];
var ref = {A:14, K:13, Q:12, J:11, T:10, 9:9, 8:8, 7:7, 6:6, 5:5, 4:4, 3:3, 2:2};

array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return ref[b] - ref[a];
});

console.log(array);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kwM4/)

Now instead of using `indexOf`, I use the value from array as the index into the ref object and have it return a value I can use to sort (note: I arranged the values to match the actual card numbers).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Exactly what i wanted to learn how to do! I like that you replaced the array to the object literal, it might look "weird" for some, but to me, this this becomes more easy to understand.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one possible short approach:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return ref.indexOf(a) - ref.indexOf(b);
});
```

**N.B.:** Beware that [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method has [limited browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility), so use [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) if required. However jQuery has its own cross browser implementation called [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, specifically the "N.B" related content and about jQuery. +1 for that.